# Running DOS games under Dosbox 0.72

Tags: dos, dosbox

I am using Windows Vista and with Dosbox 0.72 to load Turbo C for programming a DOS game.  My code runs fine (both graphics and sound routines) as long as it runs under DOS shell of Turbo C (Under Dosbox).  But when I run the same code under DosBox (outside Turbo C's Dos shell), the graphics flickers, slows down and the sound cracks. Whats wrong??

Pramod

Comment: Most likely a timing issue with your graphic routine. How graphic intensive is the program?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your program gets too much memory when run standalone. You can determine how much memory is available with MEM command, and reduce this amount before running your program with LOADFIX command. You can run LOADFIX command several times, each time it will reduce free memory in the system